# Находится (или находятся) четыре установки?

Tags: орфография, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

*В настоящее время на мини-ТЭЦ в эксплуатации **находится** четыре установки.*
Или наход**я**тся? Как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта. Выбор глагольной формы зависит от того, какое значение имеет подлежащее. Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы. При подлежащем, обозначающем большое число предметов и воспринимаемом как *одно целое*, сказуемое обычно ставится в единственном числе. Если **четыре установки** - не совокупность, а просто четыре отдельных агрегата, то предложение будет выглядеть так: *В настоящее время на мини-ТЭЦ в эксплуатации наход**я**тся четыре установки*.